# circle progress bar shows wrong information

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a little js thing for monitoring the work day. The red line shows how much time has passed since 9:00 (the begining of the wok day), the orange line show the lunch time (12:15 - 13:00). The problem is the "lunch" line doesn't starts where it should. Seems like it starts at 13:30. 
P.S. first I wrote this script for 9:00-18:00 work day. And the script worked correctly. But now the work day is from 9:00-16:45, so I had to make changes to the code, but something went wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/csLj7wa5/

```js
var bar = document.getElementById('progressbar');

createProgressBar = function(bar) {
 var options = {
  start: 0,
  width: bar.getAttribute('data-width'),
  height: bar.getAttribute('data-height'),
  percent: 100,
  lineWidth: bar.getAttribute('data-linewidth')
 },

 canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
 paper = canvas.getContext('2d'),
 span = document.createElement('span'),
 radius = (options.width - options.lineWidth) / 2,
 color = paper.createLinearGradient(0, 0, options.width, 0),

 end = new Date(),
 today = new Date(),

 breakStart = new Date(),
 breakEnd = new Date();


 breakStart.setHours(12, 15, 0);
 breakEnd.setHours(13, 0, 0);


 const full = 465;
 end.setHours(16, 45, 0);


 span.style.width = bar.style.width = options.width + 'px';
 span.style.height = bar.style.height = options.height + 'px';
 canvas.width = options.width;
 canvas.height = options.height;
 span.style.lineHeight = options.height + 'px';
 span.style.color = 'white';

 color = '#ff5349';

 bar.appendChild(span);
 bar.appendChild(canvas);

 function updateTime() {
  var now = new Date(),
  time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds(),
  remaining = end - now,

  _second = 1000,
  _minute = _second * 60,
  _hour = _minute * 60,
  _day = _hour * 24,

  hours = Math.floor((remaining % _day) / _hour),
  minutes = Math.floor((remaining % _hour) / _minute),
  seconds = Math.floor((remaining % _minute) / _second),

  current = (full - (hours * 60) - minutes) / full * 100,

  step = 1.5 + (2 * current / 100),


  startb = (breakStart.getHours() * 60 + breakStart.getMinutes()) / full * 100,
  endb = (breakEnd.getHours() * 60 + breakEnd.getMinutes()) / full * 100,

  startBr = 1.5 + (2 * startb / 100),
  endBr = 1.5 + (2 * endb / 100);

     createCircle(options, paper, radius, color, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * step);
     createBreak(options, paper, radius, color, Math.PI * startBr, Math.PI * endBr);

  setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
 };

 updateTime();
},

createCircle = function(options, paper, radius, color, start, end) {
 paper.clearRect(
  options.width / 2 - radius - options.lineWidth,
  options.height / 2 - radius - options.lineWidth,
  radius * 2 + (options.lineWidth * 2),
  radius * 2 + (options.lineWidth * 2)
 );

 paper.beginPath();
 paper.arc(options.width / 2, options.height / 2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
 paper.strokeStyle = 'white';
 paper.lineCap = 'butt';
 paper.lineWidth = options.lineWidth;
 paper.stroke();
 paper.closePath();

 paper.beginPath();
 paper.arc(options.width / 2, options.height / 2, radius, start, end, false);
 paper.strokeStyle = color;
 paper.lineCap = 'butt';
 paper.lineWidth = options.lineWidth;
 paper.stroke();
 paper.closePath();
},

createBreak = function(options, paper, radius, color, start, end) {
 paper.beginPath();
 paper.arc(options.width / 2, options.height / 2, 171, start, end, false);
 paper.strokeStyle = 'orange';
 paper.lineCap = 'butt';
 paper.lineWidth = 19;
 paper.stroke();
 paper.closePath();
};

createProgressBar(bar);
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #333;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'sans serif', Verdana, Tahoma, Helvetica;
}

canvas {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}

#progressbar {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -180px;
 margin-left: -180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar" data-width="360" data-height="360" data-linewidth="16"></div>
```